# How can I print array in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, calling-convention

I want to print result array, which has 3000 elements. I wrote this code:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.text
.globl main
main:
mov ecx, 3000
mov edx, offset result
llp:

mov al,[edx]
push eax
mov eax, offset message
push eax
call printf
add esp, 8
inc edx

loop llp
mov eax, 0
ret

.data
message : 
.asciz " Wynik: %i\n"
```

The problem is, that program prints only first element 3000 times. What should I change?

**UPDATE**

solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ecx` and `edx` are caller-saved registers, meaning they can be freely used in called functions such as the `printf`. You are lucky you even got 3000 items printed. One possible solution is to save and restore those registers using the stack around the `call printf`:

```
llp:

mov al,[edx]
push ecx
push edx
push eax
mov eax, offset message
push eax
call printf
add esp, 8
pop edx
pop ecx
inc edx

loop llp
```